# Sitecore Commerce Sellable item variants

Tags: sitecore-commerce

I am trying to get the product variants from a SellableItem but I can't seem to be able to find the Variant item.

Below are the steps that I am doing currently

1A) Get sellable item

```
var sellableItemId = "myid"
SellableItem item = container.SellableItems.Where(x => x.ProductId == sellableItemId ))..FirstOrDefault()

return item.ItemVariations;
```

1B) This returns a list of variantIds.

```
"57042066|57042067|57042068|57042069|57042070"
```

2A) I tried using similar code below to retrieve the variant item, but it is not able to find anything.

```
var variantId = "57042066";
var variant = container.SellableItems.Where(x => x.ProductId == variantId));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do 2A step.

SellableItem already contains `Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Catalog.ItemVariationsComponent`.
Inside of `Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Catalog.ItemVariationsComponent` you will find `ChildComponents` property, which contains array of `Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Catalog.ItemVariationComponent`.

See example:

[image]